# Python script for monitoring Admin Console properties in Webshpere

Tags: python, scripting, websphere, ibm-mq, jacl

I've a requirement for writing a script in Python or JACL script in which I need to monitor and pull the information from Admin Console of the application running on remote server. I require to pull following information:

- jdbc
- jms
- web container threads
- default work manager threads.

If anyone can help me writing this script, it'll be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file called config.py and paste the follwing into it.

```
#
## Récupération du fichier de config à partir des paramètres du script
#
import sys
if (len(sys.argv) > 0):
configFile = sys.argv[0]
else:
configFile = 'F:\config.xml'

#
### Variables d'environnement du script
#
server = AdminControl.queryNames('node='+AdminControl.getNode( )+',type=Server,*')
serverName = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, "name")
nodeName = AdminControl.getNode( )
cellName = AdminControl.getCell( )

# scope à remplacer par cluster=clusterName lorsqu'applicable??
scope = ' -node '+nodeName+' -server '+serverName
scopeAlt = ' -scope Node='+nodeName+',Server='+serverName
scopeConfig =       'server(cells/'+cellName+'/nodes/'+nodeName+'/servers/'+serverName+'|server.xml)'
scopeResources = 'cells/'+cellName+'/nodes/'+nodeName+'/servers/'+serverName+'|resources.xml'
authPrefix = nodeName


#
### Fonctions utilitaires
#
def getAttributeD(xmlElement, name, default):
if xmlElement.hasAttribute(name):
    return xmlElement.getAttribute(name)
return default

def getAttribute(xmlElement, name):
return xmlElement.getAttribute(name)

_regBuses = {}
def addBus(bus):
_regBuses[bus['name']] = bus

def getBus(busName):
return _regBuses[busName]

_regDataProviders = {}
def getDataProviderId(providerName):
if providerName in _regDataProviders.keys():
    return _regDataProviders[providerName]
ps = AdminJDBC.listJDBCProviders(providerName)
if len(ps) > 0:
    p = ps[0]
else:
    print("JDBC Provider non trouve : " + providerName)
    p = providerName
_regDataProviders[providerName] = p
return p

#
### Lecture du fichier de config
#
print('Lecture du fichier de config : ' + configFile)
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory as DocumentBuilderFactory
dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
document = db.parse(configFile)
config = document.getDocumentElement()


#
### JVM properties
#
jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine')
props = config.getElementsByTagName('property')
for i in range(props.getLength()):
xmle = props.item(i)
propName = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
propValue = getAttribute(xmle, 'value')
propDesc = getAttributeD(xmle, 'description', '')
propRequired = getAttributeD(xmle, 'required', 'false')
print('Creation de la propriete JVM : ' + propName)
AdminConfig.create('Property', jvm, '[[validationExpression ""] [name "'+propName+'"] [description "'+propDesc+'"] [value "'+propValue+'"] [required "'+propRequired+'"]]')


# 
### Authentication
#
auths = config.getElementsByTagName('authentication')
for i in range(auths.getLength()):
xmle = auths.item(i)
name = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
user = getAttribute(xmle, 'user')
pwd = getAttribute(xmle, 'password')
desc = getAttributeD(xmle, 'description', '')
print('Creation de l\'authentification : ' + name)
AdminTask.createAuthDataEntry('[-alias '+name+' -user '+user+' -password "'+pwd+'" -  description "'+desc+'" ]')


#
### JDBC Providers
#
providers = config.getElementsByTagName('jdbcProvider')
for i in range(providers.getLength()):
xmle = providers.item(i)
name = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
shortName = getAttributeD(xmle, 'shortName', name)
dbType = getAttribute(xmle, 'databaseType')
providerType = getAttribute(xmle, 'providerType')
implementationType = getAttribute(xmle,  'implementationType')
classPath = getAttribute(xmle,  'classPath')
nativePath = getAttribute(xmle,  'nativePath')
desc = getAttributeD(xmle,  'description', '')
print('Creation du fournisseur JDBC : ' + name)
AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('['+scopeAlt+' -databaseType '+dbType+' -providerType "'+providerType+'" -implementationType "'+implementationType+'" -name "'+name+'" -description "'+desc+'" -classpath ['+classPath+'] -nativePath ['+nativePath+' ] ]')

#
### JDBC Datasources
#
dss = config.getElementsByTagName('jdbcDataSource')
for i in range(dss.getLength()):
xmle = dss.item(i)
name = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
jndiName = getAttribute(xmle, 'jndiName')
providerName = getAttribute(xmle, 'jdbcProvider')
auth = getAttribute(xmle, 'authentication')
dbName = getAttribute(xmle, 'database')
dbHost = getAttribute(xmle, 'host')
dbPort = getAttribute(xmle, 'port')
dataStoreHelperClassName = getAttributeD(xmle, 'dataStoreHelperClassName', 'com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper')
print('Creation de la source de données : ' + name)
providerId = getDataProviderId(providerName)
authX = authPrefix + '/' + auth
AdminTask.createDatasource(providerId, '[-name '+name+' -jndiName '+jndiName+' -  dataStoreHelperClassName '+dataStoreHelperClassName+' -containerManagedPersistence false -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias '+authX+' -xaRecoveryAuthAlias '+authX+' -configureResourceProperties [[databaseName java.lang.String '+dbName+'] [driverType java.lang.Integer 4] [serverName java.lang.String '+dbHost+'] [portNumber java.lang.Integer '+dbPort+']]]')


#   
### Internal & External Buses (JMS)
#
buses = config.getElementsByTagName('internalBus')
for i in range(buses.getLength()):
xmle = buses.item(i)
busName = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
busDesc = getAttributeD(xmle, 'description', '')
logSize = getAttributeD(xmle, 'logSize', '100')
minStoreSize = getAttributeD(xmle, 'minStoreSize', '200')
maxStoreSize = getAttributeD(xmle, 'minStoreSize', '500')
unlimitedStoreSize = getAttributeD(xmle, 'unlimitedStoreSize', 'false')
print('Creation du bus interne : ' + busName)
AdminTask.createSIBus('[-bus '+busName+' -description ['+busDesc+'] -busSecurity false]')
AdminTask.addSIBusMember('[-bus '+busName+' ' + scope + ' -fileStore  -logSize '+logSize+' -minPermanentStoreSize '+minStoreSize+' -maxPermanentStoreSize '+maxStoreSize+' -unlimitedPermanentStoreSize '+unlimitedStoreSize+' -minTemporaryStoreSize '+minStoreSize+' -maxTemporaryStoreSize '+maxStoreSize+' -unlimitedTemporaryStoreSize '+unlimitedStoreSize+' ]')
bus = {}
bus['name'] = busName
bus['type'] = 'internal'
addBus(bus)


buses = config.getElementsByTagName('externalBus')
for i in range(buses.getLength()):
xmle = buses.item(i)
bus = {}
busName = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
print('Creation du bus externe : ' + busName)
bus['name'] = busName
bus['type'] = 'external'
bus['manager'] = getAttribute(xmle, 'manager')
bus['host'] = getAttribute(xmle, 'host')
bus['port'] = getAttribute(xmle, 'port')
bus['channel'] = getAttribute(xmle, 'channel')
addBus(bus)


#
### JMS Connections Factories
#
wmqRes = '"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider('+scopeResources+'#builtin_mqprovider)"'
cfs = config.getElementsByTagName('jmsConnectionFactory')
for i in range(cfs.getLength()):
xmle = cfs.item(i)
busName = getAttribute(xmle, 'bus')
jmsType = getAttribute(xmle, 'jmsType')
cfName = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
cfJndiName = getAttribute(xmle, 'jndiName')
cfDesc = getAttributeD(xmle, 'description', '')
nonPersistentMapping=getAttributeD(xmle, 'nonPersistentMapping', 'ExpressNonPersistent')
persistentMapping=getAttributeD(xmle, 'persistentMapping', 'ReliablePersistent')
wmqTransportType=getAttributeD(xmle, 'wmqTransportType', 'BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT')
print('Creation de la fabrique de connection jms : ' + cfName)
bus = getBus(busName)
if bus['type'] == 'internal':
    AdminTask.createSIBJMSConnectionFactory(scopeConfig, '[-type '+jmsType+' -name '+cfName+' -jndiName '+cfJndiName+' -description "'+cfDesc+'" -category  -busName '+busName+' -nonPersistentMapping '+nonPersistentMapping+' -readAhead Default -tempQueueNamePrefix  -target  -targetType BusMember -targetSignificance Preferred -targetTransportChain  -providerEndPoints  -connectionProximity Bus -authDataAlias  -containerAuthAlias  -mappingAlias  -shareDataSourceWithCMP false -logMissingTransactionContext false -manageCachedHandles false -xaRecoveryAuthAlias  -persistentMapping '+persistentMapping+' -consumerDoesNotModifyPayloadAfterGet false -producerDoesNotModifyPayloadAfterSet false]')
else:
    if jmsType == 'topic':
        cfType = 'TCF'
    else:
        cfType = 'TCF'
    AdminTask.createWMQConnectionFactory(wmqRes, '[-type '+cfType+' -name '+cfName+' -jndiName '+cfJndiName+' -description "'+cfDesc+'" -qmgrName ' +bus['manager']+ ' -wmqTransportType '+wmqTransportType+' -qmgrHostname '+bus['host']+' -qmgrPortNumber '+bus['port']+' -qmgrSvrconnChannel '+bus['channel']+' ]')


#
### Destinations JMS
#
dests = config.getElementsByTagName('jmsDestination')
for i in range(dests.getLength()):
xmle = dests.item(i)
busName = getAttribute(xmle, 'bus')
jmsType = getAttribute(xmle, 'jmsType')
destName = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
destJndiName = getAttribute(xmle, 'jndiName')
destDest = getAttribute(xmle, 'destination')
destDesc = getAttributeD(xmle, 'description', '')
reliability = getAttributeD(xmle, 'reliability', 'EXPRESS_NONPERSISTENT')
deliveryMode = getAttributeD(xmle, 'deliveryMode', 'NonPersistent')
print('Creation de la destination jms : ' + destName)
bus = getBus(busName)
if bus['type'] == 'internal':
    if jmsType == 'queue':
        sibType = 'Queue'
    elif jmsType == 'topic':
        sibType = 'Topic'
    AdminTask.createSIBDestination('[-bus '+busName+' -name '+destDest+' -type '+sibType+' -reliability '+reliability+' -description "'+destDesc+'" '+scope+' ]')
    if jmsType == 'queue':
        AdminTask.createSIBJMSQueue(scopeConfig, '[-name '+destName+' -jndiName '+destJndiName+' -description "'+destDesc+'" -deliveryMode '+deliveryMode+' -readAhead AsConnection -busName '+busName+' -queueName '+destDest+' -scopeToLocalQP false -producerBind false -producerPreferLocal true -gatherMessages false]')
    elif jmsType == 'topic':
        AdminTask.createSIBJMSTopic(scopeConfig, '[-name '+destName+' -jndiName '+destJndiName+' -description "'+destDesc+'" -topicName -deliveryMode '+deliveryMode+' -readAhead AsConnection -busName '+busName+' -topicSpace '+destDest+']')
else:
    if jmsType == 'queue':
        AdminTask.createWMQQueue(scopeConfig, '[-name '+destName+' -jndiName '+destJndiName+' -queueName '+destDest+' -qmgr  -description "'+destDesc+'" ]')
    elif jmsType == 'topic':
        AdminTask.createWMQTopic(scopeConfig, '[-name '+destName+' -jndiName '+destJndiName+' -topicName '+destDest+' -description "'+destDesc+'" ]')


#
### JMS Activation Specs
#
wmqRes = '"WebSphere MQ JMS Provider('+scopeResources+'#builtin_mqprovider)"'
specs = config.getElementsByTagName('jmsActivationSpec')
for i in range(specs.getLength()):
xmle = specs.item(i)
busName = getAttribute(xmle, 'bus')
specName = getAttribute(xmle, 'name')
specJndiName = getAttribute(xmle, 'jndiName')
jmsType = getAttribute(xmle, 'jmsType')
destJndiName = getAttribute(xmle, 'jndiDestinationName')
specDesc = getAttributeD(xmle, 'description', '')
maxHandlers = getAttributeD(xmle, 'maxHandlers', '4')
wmqTransportType=getAttributeD(xmle, 'wmqTransportType', 'BINDINGS_THEN_CLIENT')
print('Creation de la spec d\'activation jms : ' + specName)
if jmsType == 'queue':
    jmsDestClass = 'Queue'
elif jmsType == 'topic':
    jmsDestClass = 'Topic'
bus = getBus(busName)
if bus['type'] == 'internal':
    AdminTask.createSIBJMSActivationSpec(scopeConfig, '[-name '+specName+' -   jndiName '+specJndiName+' -destinationJndiName '+destJndiName+' -description "'+specDesc+'" -busName '+busName+' -clientId  -durableSubscriptionHome  -destinationType javax.jms.'+jmsDestClass+' -messageSelector  -acknowledgeMode Auto-acknowledge -subscriptionName  -maxBatchSize 1 -maxConcurrency '+maxHandlers+' -subscriptionDurability NonDurable -shareDurableSubscriptions InCluster -authenticationAlias  -readAhead Default -target  -targetType BusMember -targetSignificance Preferred -targetTransportChain  -providerEndPoints  -shareDataSourceWithCMP false -consumerDoesNotModifyPayloadAfterGet false -forwarderDoesNotModifyPayloadAfterSet false -alwaysActivateAllMDBs false -retryInterval 30 -autoStopSequentialMessageFailure 0 -failingMessageDelay 0]')
else:
    AdminTask.createWMQActivationSpec(wmqRes, '[-name '+specName+' -jndiName '+specJndiName+' -description "'+specDesc+'" -destinationJndiName '+destJndiName+' -destinationType javax.jms.'+jmsDestClass+' -qmgrName '+bus['manager']+' -wmqTransportType '+wmqTransportType+' -qmgrHostname '+bus['host']+' -qmgrPortNumber '+bus['port']+' -qmgrSvrconnChannel '+bus['channel']+' ]')



AdminConfig.save()
```

then copy this code in a file called config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>

<!-- Definition des propriétés JVM -->
<property 
    name="someproperty" 
    value="myvalue" 
/>
<property 
    description="Different jvm properties"
    name="myproperty" 
    value="true" 
/>

<!-- Définition des sources d'authentification  -->
<authentication
    description="Authentification pour accès DB"
    name="auth"
    user="dbuser"
    password="dbuser"
/>


<!-- Définition des fournisseurs JDBC -->
<jdbcProvider
    description="One-phase commit DB2 JCC provider that supports JDBC 3.0."
    shortName="DB2"
    name="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider"
    databaseType="DB2"
    providerType="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider"
    implementationType="Source de données du pool de connexions"
    classPath="${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc.jar ${UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc_license_cu.jar ${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"
    nativePath="${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_NATIVEPATH}"
/>
<jdbcProvider
    description="Two-phase commit DB2 JCC provider that supports JDBC 3.0."
    shortName="DB2(XA)"
    name="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider (XA)"
    databaseType="DB2"
    providerType="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider"
    implementationType="Source de données XA"
    classPath="${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc.jar ${UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc_license_cu.jar ${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"
    nativePath="${DB2UNIVERSAL_JDBC_DRIVER_NATIVEPATH}"
/>


<!-- Définition des sources de données JDBC --> 
<jdbcDataSource
    description="Sources de données des Demandes"
    name="db_name"
    jndiName="jdbc/db_name"
    jdbcProvider="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider (XA)"
    authentication="auth"
    database="DB2XXXXX"
    host="hostname"
    port="00000"
/>


<!-- Définition des bus internes -->
<internalBus 
    description="Bus Interne"
    name="BusInterne" 
/>

<!-- Définition des bus externes -->
<externalBus 
    description="Serveur Websphere MQ externe"
    name="ServeurMQ" 
    manager="Manager" 
    host="host" 
    port="1414" 
    channel="CLIENT.NAME"
/>

<!-- Définition des Fabriques de Connexions JMS-->
<jmsConnectionFactory 
    description="Queue de rafraichissement des demandes"
    name="QCF" 
    jndiName="jms/QCF" 
    jmsType="queue" 
    bus='BusInterne' 
/>
<jmsConnectionFactory 
    description="Topic "
    name="TCF" 
    jndiName="jms/TCF" 
    jmsType="topic" 
    bus='ServeurMQ' 
/>

<!-- Définition des Destinations JMS -->
<jmsDestination 
    description="Queue "
    name="queue" 
    jndiName="jms/queue" 
    jmsType="queue" 
    bus='BusInterne' 
    destination="Q.NAME" 
/>
<jmsDestination 
    description="Topic 2"
    name="topic2" 
    jndiName="topic2" 
    jmsType="topic" 
    bus='ServeurMQ' 
    destination="Q.TOPIC.NAME" 
/>

<!-- Définition des Spécifications d'Activation JMS -->
<jmsActivationSpec 
    description="Spec"
    name="Specs" 
    jndiName="jms/Specs" 
    jmsType="queue" 
    bus='BusInterne' 
    jndiDestinationName="jms/queue" 
    maxHandlers="4" 
/>

</config>
```

After all of the resources defined in the config.xml file, simply call the following
from a command prompt. Make sure you have access to wsadmin.

```
wsadmin -lang jython -profileName MyProfile -f config.py config.xml
```

This will create all your resources into a profile called MyProfile.

Hope it helps.